# How to get fingerprint dat in ios 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

For this i use La Authentication framework but with the help of that i don't got fingerprint data and it just returns me boolean value i.e true and false , so it cant help i want fingerprint data in variable so further i will process it.
Help me.

following is the sample code,

```
func authenticateUser() {
  ...

  // Check if the device can evaluate the policy.
  if context.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
    [context .evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reasonString, reply: { (success: Bool, evalPolicyError: NSError?) -> Void in

      if success {

      }
      else {
        // If authentication failed then show a message to the console with a short description.
        // In case that the error is a user fallback, then show the password alert view.
        println(evalPolicyError?.localizedDescription)

        switch evalPolicyError!.code {
          case LAError.SystemCancel.toRaw():
            println("Authentication was cancelled by the system")

          case LAError.UserCancel.toRaw():
            println("Authentication was cancelled by the user")

          case LAError.UserFallback.toRaw():
            println("User selected to enter custom password")
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
              self.showPasswordAlert()
            })

          default:
            println("Authentication failed")
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
              self.showPasswordAlert()
            })
        }
      }
    })]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, Apple does not allow access to the fingerprint data. This has to do with security.

The iOS SDK only allows you let a user validate them selfs with the Touch ID.

Comment: Can you tell me that Westpac and RBS bank how implement in their mobile application ? Can you have any idea of this?

Comment: With the code you posted, you check whether the user is validated with Touch ID

Comment: it is an just sample code but i want to do with in our bank application, and if in my i phone there are more than 1 fingerprints are added then it cause security bridge?? What you think how should i implement?

Comment: Touch ID does not differentiate between the user, thus all the user will will checked and you are not informed about the user who's fingerprint is scanned.